# Use select in angular to pass multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular Js is there a way to use a select element the same way you can with a list of links?

For example if I have some links like this:

```
<a ng-click="ctrl.change('argument1','argument2')">One</a>
<a ng-click="ctrl.change('argument3','argument4')">Two</a>
...
```

Is there a way I can do the same thing with a select element?

```
<select>
    <option value="argument1,argument2">One</option>
    <option value="argument3,argument4">Two</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: How about `ng-change` ?

Comment: I thought about that, but I can't figure out how to do it with multiple arguments. Any thoughts?

Comment: Like `<select ng-change='ctrl.change('argument1','argument2')'>`

Comment: How would that work with different arguments from each select option?

Comment: I think you have an array of objects, just pass object values as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the variables and model through `ng-change` , hope below code helps you,

**template**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <select ng-model="item" ng-options="i.name for i in items" ng-change="changed('hello','world',item)">
            <option value="">choose items</option>
        </select>
 </div>
```

**controller**

```
function myCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{

            "name": "first",
            "type" : "type1"

    }, {

            "name": "second",
            "type" : "type2"

    }, {

            "name": "third",
            "type" : "type3"

    }];


    $scope.changed = function (hello,world,item) {
        alert(hello); // argument1
        alert(world); //argument2
        alert(item.type); //model argument based on the selection
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

do u mean this? use controller value instead of scope value if u wish

```html
<select ng-options="['a,b','c,d']" ng-model="selected" ng-change="ctrl.change(selected)">
```